# How to construct a sequence of continuous matrix transformations along a closed 3D path?

Tags: rust, linear-algebra, game-physics

I want to create a sequence of 4x4 spatial transformation matrices which can be used to smoothly transform an object as it moves along a closed 3D path.

The code below demonstrates how I am currently constructing the transformation matrices (`xforms`): by deriving the vectors representing the axes of the transform coordinate system. The loop is iterating over 3-tuple windows of points along a path, and building a matrix for each window based on the direction of travel.

I was able to achieve smoothly varying motion by incrementally updating the `up` y-axis reference. However, I am struggling to come up with a good strategy to avoid the seam/discontinuity between the beginning/end of the path.

For this particular problem, the specific initial orientation is not important, as long as it is reached again smoothly by the end of loop. The main goal is to keep the object pointed forwards in the direction of the path, and minimize the amount of unnecessary roll (rotation about the forward axis).

```
let mut up = Y_AXIS;
let mut xforms = Vec::new();
let mut coords = Paths3::new();

for (&prev, &curr, &next) in lissa_path.iter().circular_tuple_windows() {
    let forward = (next - prev).unit();
    let right = up.cross(forward).unit();
    up = forward.cross(right).unit();

    let mut m = M44::identity();
    m.set_x_axis(right)
        .set_y_axis(up)
        .set_z_axis(forward)
        .set_translate(curr);

    let arrow_len = 0.2;
    coords.push(arrow(curr, curr + right.scale(0.5 * arrow_len)));
    coords.push(arrow(curr, curr + up.scale(arrow_len)));
    // coords.push(arrow(curr, curr + forward.scale(arrow_len)));

    xforms.push(m);
}
```

The diagram below visualizes the coordinate systems for each transformation matrix created in the loop above. The local coordinate system x-axes are the shorter arms. The y-axes are the longer arms. The z-axes has been omitted for clarity. The red circle highlights the problem I am trying to solve. There is a discontinuity in the transform coordinate systems between the end and beginning of the path.
[image: diagram of transformation axes]

EDIT: I attempted the following, where I am using simple approximations to derive the tangent, and normal vectors. It fixes the begin/end discontinuity, but seems to introduce a lot of extra twisting. This observation matches the problem in the [RMF paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Computation-of-rotation-minimizing-frames.pdf).

```
fn get_xforms(path: &[V3]) -> Vec<M44> {
    let mut xforms = Vec::new();
    for (&prev, &curr, &next) in path.iter().circular_tuple_windows() {
        let tangent = (next - prev).unit();
        let t1 = (curr - prev).unit();
        let t2 = (next - curr).unit();
        let normal = (t2 - t1).unit();
        let binormal = tangent.cross(normal).unit();

        let mut m = M44::identity();
        m.set_x_axis(normal)
            .set_y_axis(binormal)
            .set_z_axis(tangent)
            .set_translate(curr);

        xforms.push(m);
    }
    xforms
}
```

Frenet frames of my curve with normal+binormal vectors shown.

[image: frenet frame coordinates]

The RMF paper achieves this behavior (f), which is exactly what I want. I will be pursuing this next.

[image: RMF paper results]

EDIT2: I did not pursue RMF paper next. I did something else, which is giving me satisfactory results. I used my original technique to generate the first pass transforms, and then a second pass to apply a twist gradient to each transform to make up for the delta between the first and last coordinate systems. I'm using [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/how-can-i-derive-the-rotation-matrix-from-the-axis-angle-rotation-vector) for calculation of axis-angle rotation matrix. Here is the code:

```
fn get_xforms(path: &[V3]) -> Vec<M44> {
    let mut xforms = Vec::new();
    let mut up = Y_AXIS;

    for (&prev, &curr, &next) in path.iter().circular_tuple_windows() {
        let forward = (next - prev).unit();
        let right = up.cross(forward).unit();
        up = forward.cross(right).unit();

        let mut m = M44::identity();
        m.set_x_axis(right)
            .set_y_axis(up)
            .set_z_axis(forward)
            .set_translate(curr);

        xforms.push(m);
    }
    xforms
}

fn twist_xforms(xforms: &[M44]) -> Vec<M44> {
    let first_y = xforms[0].get_y_axis();
    let last_y = xforms.last().unwrap().get_y_axis();
    let angle = last_y.dot(first_y).acos();
    let mut result = Vec::new();

    for (i, xform) in xforms.iter().enumerate() {
        let frac = i as f64 / xforms.len() as f64;

        let right = xform.get_x_axis();
        let up = xform.get_y_axis();
        let forward = xform.get_z_axis();
        let translate = xform.get_translate();

        let mut m = M44::identity();
        m.set_x_axis(right).set_y_axis(up).set_z_axis(forward);
        m *= M44::rotate_axis_angle(forward, frac * angle);
        m.set_translate(translate);
        result.push(m);
    }

    result
}
```

[image: updated 2-pass twist method]

Comment: `forward` is determined by the path, there is a degree of freedom in choosing `right` and `up`. The natural choice would be to use the curve normal as `right`. You're already using a first order approximation for the curve tangent as `forward`. The perpendicular component of the change in `forward` can be `right`. This works for the path depicted, but would have problems if the second derivative isn't continuous or doesn't uniquely define the normal, on linear paths for example.

Comment: This makes perfect sense @kalhartt! Your reply helped me find this related question, and paper which is about exactly my problem! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843307/getting-consistent-normals-along-a-3d-bezier-curve

Comment: Another related topic: Frenet-Serret formulas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Rotation Minimizing Frames](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Computation-of-rotation-minimizing-frames.pdf) technique cited from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843307/getting-consistent-normals-along-a-3d-bezier-curve) along with the axis-angle rotation matrix from [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/how-can-i-derive-the-rotation-matrix-from-the-axis-angle-rotation-vector) to twist the frames to close the discontinuity.

```rust
fn rotation_minimizing_frames(path: &[V3], tangents: &[V3], initial: M44) -> Vec<M44> {
    assert_eq!(path.len(), tangents.len());
    let mut frames = vec![initial];

    for i in 0..(path.len() - 1) {
        let ri = frames[i].get_y_axis();
        let ti = tangents[i];
        let ti1 = tangents[i + 1];
        let xi = path[i];
        let xi1 = path[i + 1];

        let v1 = xi1 - xi;
        let c1 = v1.dot(v1);
        let ril = ri - (2. / c1) * v1.dot(ri) * v1;
        let til = ti - (2. / c1) * v1.dot(ti) * v1;
        let v2 = ti1 - til;
        let c2 = v2.dot(v2);
        let ri1 = ril - (2. / c2) * v2.dot(ril) * v2;
        let si1 = ti1.cross(ri1);
        let ui1 = M44::from_axes(si1, ri1, ti1, xi1);
        frames.push(ui1);
    }

    frames
}

fn twist_xforms(xforms: &[M44]) -> Vec<M44> {
    let first_y = xforms[0].get_y_axis();
    let last_y = xforms.last().unwrap().get_y_axis();
    let angle = last_y.dot(first_y).acos();
    let mut result = Vec::new();

    for (i, xform) in xforms.iter().enumerate() {
        let frac = i as f64 / xforms.len() as f64;

        let right = xform.get_x_axis();
        let up = xform.get_y_axis();
        let forward = xform.get_z_axis();
        let translate = xform.get_translate();

        let mut m = M44::from_axes(right, up, forward, ORIGIN);
        m *= M44::rotate_axis_angle(forward, frac * angle);
        m.set_translate(translate);
        result.push(m);
    }

    result
}

fn run(path: &[V3]) -> Vec<M44> {
    let tangents = get_tangents(&path);
    let forward = tangents[0];
    let right = -Y_AXIS.cross(forward);
    let up = right.cross(forward);
    let initial = M44::from_axes(right, up, forward, path[0]);
    let xforms = rotation_minimizing_frames(&path, &tangents, initial);
    let xforms = twist_xforms(&xforms);
    xforms
}
```

[image: picture of rotation minimizing frames with twist]